# Download AOSP mirror branch from external device over ssh

Tags: android, android-source

I wanted to setup an enviroment as :

1) I downloaded the mirror of AOSP on external drive.

2) Now I wanted to use this external drive as local copy from where multiple users can access the AOSP download and create a branch over ssh.

How can I achieve this? 
 I tried with

```
repo init -u `ssh root@ipaddress:path to manifest.git` -b androidx.x.x
```

But it throws error for -u.

Help me in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: See https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#using-a-local-mirror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used :

```
 repo init -u username@ipaddress:path to manifest.git -b androidx.x.x
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Did you see the link I posted as a comment to your question? And what do you mean by "I dont know how I can do same over the ssh". Your command _does_ use SSH. Or do you mean how other people can use SSH to sync from what you've downloaded?

Comment: "It's possible to store the mirror on a LAN server and to access it over NFS, SSH or Git." What is the meaning of ssh here? Like I explained I am accessing the external drive in an intranet environment.

Comment: Okay, but assuming that you'll attach this drive to one of the computers connected to your network, how do you intend to access its contents? SSH would be one method, i.e. computers use SSH to connect to the computer with the drive attached.